# Clean copied files from external project

Tags: cmake

As a part of my build process I'm building the webserver [lighttpd](https://www.lighttpd.net/2016/12/24/1.4.44/).

The following `CMakeLists.txt` is working:

```
include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(
    lighttpd
    URL ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/lighttpd.tar.gz
    CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${EXTERNAL_OUTPUT_PATH}/lighttpd
)

ExternalProject_Add_Step(
    lighttpd copy2bin
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${EXTERNAL_OUTPUT_PATH}/lighttpd/sbin ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${EXTERNAL_OUTPUT_PATH}/lighttpd/lib/lighttpd ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}
    DEPENDEES install
)
```

When I type `make`, the resulting binaries and libraries are in `bin/` and `lib/` respectively as done in the `copy2bin` step. However, when I type `make clean` the files are not cleared out.

How can I notify CMake to also clear out `bin/` and `lib/` lighttpd files when invoking `clean`?

Is there a better way I could be doing this? I basically modeled it after one I found on [GitHub](https://github.com/mfreiholz/cmake-example-external-project/blob/master/CMakeLists-ExternalProjects.txt).

This is my top level CMakeLists:

```
# Specify the minimum version for CMake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

# Project's name
project(CMakeTest)

# Set the output folder where your program will be created
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(EXTERNAL_OUTPUT_PATH   ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/ext_install)

add_subdirectory(ext) #Contains CMakeLists above
```

Edit:

I was able to get it working with:

```
set_property(DIRECTORY PROPERTY ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES
    "${EXTERNAL_OUTPUT_PATH}"
    "${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/lighttpd"
    "${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/lighttpd-angel"
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`set_directory_properties`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_directory_properties.html) with [`ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES.html) allows to add files to clean during the make clean stage:

```
set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES "${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}")
set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES "${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}")
```

I used separate calls to `set_directory_properties` because of its signature:

```
set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES prop1 value1 prop2 value2)
```

This allows to associate a property with only one value. An all-in-one solution would look like this:

```
set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES
    ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES "${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}"
    ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES "${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}"
)
```

I don't like the `ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES` repetition in the same call. Alternatively, you can use [`set_property`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html):

```
set_property(DIRECTORY APPEND PROPERTY ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES
    "${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}"
    "${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}"
)
```

---

**Note:**

When using a variable in a path, you should always write the path between quotes `""`: if the variable contains a space character, the resulting path may be considered as a list of value:

```
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "/path/with a/space")
set_property(DIRECTORY APPEND PROPERTY ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES
    ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}
)
```

In the code above, `${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}` without quotes will be interpreted as follows:

```
set_property(DIRECTORY APPEND PROPERTY ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES
    /path/with a/space
)
```

Here the property will not be applied to the path `/path/with a/space` as wanted, but to the paths `/path/with` and `a/space`.

Comment: Hmm, I tried this, but `lighttpd` is still showing up inside `${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}` even after a `make clean` or `ninja clean`

Comment: Did it work in `${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}`? Please edit your question and add the exact content of `bin/` and `lib/`

Comment: No, the lighttpd files were neither cleared out of `bin/` nor `lib/`. I updated my question to give some more context

Comment: I think I misunderstood how `set_directory_properties` works. Try to use the path of each file you want to clean instead of the path to their directory

Comment: As of CMake 3.15, `ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES` is deprecated, and use of the shorter [`ADDITIONAL_CLEAN_FILES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/ADDITIONAL_CLEAN_FILES.html#prop_dir:ADDITIONAL_CLEAN_FILES) variable is recommended instead.